# PHP $_Server Not Working Properly

Tags: php, string, variables, string-interpolation

I have the following line:

```
<div class='social'>http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]</div>
```

It's all great and it displays the current link, let's say: http://www.example.com/mypage.php

Now I want to associate this with a variable as such

```
$myURL = 'http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]'
```

When I echo this out I get "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" - in other words the code itself. What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried: 
$myURL = '{http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]}'

I've also tried echoing it out directly:

```
echo 'http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]';
```

What am I overlooking? Thank you!

Comment: Use double quote instead of single quote !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables are not interpolated when in single quotes. Use double quotes:

```
$myURL = "http://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']";
```

Or, for clarity:

```
$myURL = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$myURL = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$myURL = sprintf("http://%%",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST],$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: I'm now getting "Notice: Use of undefined constant HTTP_HOST - assumed 'HTTP_HOST' in" and "Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' in"

Comment: Make sure to put your array keys in quotes